# having trouble getting webpack to emit my images

Tags: webpack

I have a large project that I'm trying to convert to using the webpack build system. I'm close, but I'm hitting one issue.

I created a git repository to demonstrate my issue:

https://github.com/scottschafer/webpack-image-issue.git

My CSS (and LESS) use url() references like so:

```
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
  background-image: url('/assets/images/example.png');
}
```

This doesn't emit the 'example.png' file, and the image fails to load.

If I manually import the image like so in my index.ts file, the file is emitted, and it's loaded:
    import '@src/assets/images/example.png';

How can I fix this so that my CSS url references are automatically recognized and emitted?